# VB.NET ADODB MS SQL Server Open Recordset

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

After I open a `SqlConnection`, I try to open a recordset like I did it thousands times before in VBA. Yes, I know that there are differences between VBA and VB.NET, but maybe it's to simple to see it.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Const m_cstrCnnString As String = "MyCorrectCnnString"
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    Dim rcs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Private Sub MyConnection()
        cnn = New SqlConnection(m_cstrCnnString)
        cnn.Open()
        'so far it works, my cnn.State is 1
        rcs.Open("SELECT * FROM dbo.myTable", cnn) 'this line doesn´t work
    End Sub
```

I tried the `rcs.Open` with and without `CursorTypeEnum`, `LockTypeEnum`, but I always get the same error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The arguments are of the wrong type, are out of scope, or are inconsistent with each other.

Background: Win10, Connection to a MS SQL Server Express by VB.NET.
First I import System.Data.SqlClient
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library is activated.
Also I tried it with Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library.
And I'm new in VB.NET

Comment: Why are you mixing the .NET's `SqlConnection` and the COM's `ADODB.Recordset`? If you want to use `ADODB.Recordset`, use `ADODB.Connection` too. Although it's not clear why you would switch to VB.NET only to remain in VBA.

Comment: It is best to use only ADO.NET SqlClient in .NET applications and avoid ActiveX Data Objects (ADO classic). Classic ADO hasn't been enhanced for over 20 years.

Answer (score 3):

There's some high-level stuff I need to cover before we can get into the details of what this code should look like.

First, if you're using VB.Net, you **should not** be opening a `RecordSet` object. Recordset is from ADO, which is *not the same* as ADO.Net. You definitely can't use an ADO.Net `SqlConnection` to open a classic ADO `RecordSet`. Again: these are two completely different libraries. The classic library exists in .Net only for backwards compatibility and to aid in porting forward old code. **It should not be used for new development**.

Additionally, when you move forward to ADO.Net you need to be aware of a feature called Connection Pooling. This feature takes care of caching connection objects for you, such that it's counter-productive (uses more RAM and makes things slower) to try to keep a single connection option ready for use throughout the application. Instead, it really is better to create a new connection object for most queries.

Finally, classic ADO had a problem with properly closing resources, such that some of those older applications could occasionally even lock out the database. .Net provides a way to handle this such that you are *sure* everything is closed and disposed properly and promptly: a `Using` block.

The weakness of this mechanism is `DataReader` objects (which replace RecordSet) need the connection to remain open for the life of the reader. This makes it hard to build a good data abstraction to hide all the boiler plate code that goes with data access.

The best pattern I've seen for offering the best of both worlds requires some moderate and advanced VB.Net language features (lambda methods, iterator blocks, and IEnumerable) that are unfamiliar to many traditional VB coders. It's going to require me to go a lot deeper than normal in this answer. That said, once you wrap your head around it, the result is really nice.

To show what this might look like, I need an example that's a little more concrete. We'll pretend you have an `Employee` table with columns for ID, FirstName, and LastName, and a class `Employee` with properties of the same name:

```vb
Public Class Employee
   Public Property ID As Integer
   Public Property FirstName As String
   Public Property LastName As String

   Public Shared Function FromDataRecord(record As IDataRecord) As Employee
        Return New Employee() With {
           ID = record("ID"),
           FirstName = record("FirstName"),
           LastName = record("LastName")
        }  
    End Function
End Class
```

That's right: VB sometimes uses braces now. The `Shared` method at the end is optional, but it will help make some of what comes next easier to follow. Here is what modern ADO.Net code might look like. Pay special attention to the use of `Private` and `Public`

```vb
Public Module DB
    Private Shared Property ConnectionString As String = "MyCorrectCnnString"

    Private Iterator Function GetData(Of T)(SQL As String, transform As Func(Of IDataRecord, T), addParameters As Action(Of SqlParameterCollection)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Using cn  As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, cn)
            If addParameters IsNot Nothing Then addParameters(cmd.Parameters)

            cn.Open()
            Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While rdr.Read()
                    Yield transform(rdr) 
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Function GetEmployees() As IEnumerable(Of Employee)
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee"
        Return GetData(SQL, Employee.FromDataRecord, Nothing)
    End Function

    Public Function GetEmployeeById(ID As Integer) As Employee
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee WHERE ID= @ID"
        Return GetData(SQL, Employee.FromDataRecord, 
            Sub(pc) pc.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = ID
         ).FirstOrDefault()
    End Function
     
    Public Function GetEmployeesByLastName(LastName As String) As IEnumerable(Of Employee)
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee WHERE LastName= @LastName"
        Return GetData(SQL, Employee.FromDataRecord,
            Sub(pc) pc.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = LastName
        )
    End Function

End Module
```

Now the main part of the application **NEVER** deals in SQL directly, or even has to know there's a relational database involved. It's just calling methods on a regular module, such that the code in your form for reading data looks more like this:

```
Dim employees = DB.GetEmployeesByLastName(TextBox1.Text)
DataGridView1.DataSource = employees
```

You make similar methods in the new Module for writing INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries to save changes. These methods will end up calling the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` method, but they should **NEVER** accept an SQL statement string as input.

As an application grows you might have a number of classes with `FromDataRecord()` methods, such that you instead refactor these methods to their own Module. You might also end up with enough `Public` methods in the `DB` Module to divide them up into a number of related Modules. At this point, these Modules would all go into a separate class library project (using `Friend` in some places instead of `Private`).

Comment: Hi and thank you all for your answers. That´s a lot high quality input :-) I will implement it asap.